# Bootstrap thumbnails not aligning correctly

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

I have the following code hopefully to get the thumbnails of jigsaws in a collection, but the thumbnails are different sizes, how would I change my code to display correctly :[image]

```
    <div class="row"><?php
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {?>
  <div class = "col-sm-6 col-md-3">
  <div class = "thumbnail">
  <img src = "getimage2.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" alt = "<?php echo ucfirst($row['jigsaw_title']); ?>">
  </div>
 <div class = "caption text-center">
 <h3><?php echo ucfirst($row['jigsaw_title']); ?></h3>
 <p>
 <?php echo $row['jigsaw_size_wmm']."mm x ".$row['jigsaw_size_hmm']."mm / ".mmToIn($row['jigsaw_size_wmm'])."in x ".mmToIn($row['jigsaw_size_hmm'])."in\n"; ?>    
 <p>
<a href='#myModal1' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' id='custId' data-toggle='modal' data-id='".$row['id']."' ><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></i></a>
    <a href='#myModal2' class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' id='editrecord' data-toggle='modal' data-id='".$row['id']."'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i></a>
    <a href='#myModal3' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' id='deleterecord' data-toggle='modal' data-id='".$row['id']."'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i></a>
        </p>
     </div>
   </div>
<?php   
}
?>  
</div>
```

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using? it appears to be 3.x

Comment: <link href="../css/bootstrap-3.3.7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: a quick dirty fix is to set a max height on `.thumbnail` or set a fixed height on the image

Comment: Also, why is the fifth thumbnail 'Gazebo of prayer' where it is and not on the left under the first one?

Comment: long story short, it's because bootstrap 3 uses floating divs, and float contexts get weird. I think i have a solution, but before i answer, would you be open to changing some CSS ?

Comment: yes css changes are ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your answers in the comments, this is what I got working. Unfortunately CSS floats have many drawbacks, one of which is that weird setup you see going on with the Gazebo of prayer.

My fix alters some things to use Flexbox, which is a bit more reliable for this sort of basically-all-the-same-height-but-not-exactly sort of scenarios.

Let me know if something isn't working for you, here is a snippet I have with the basic HTML + CSS

```css
.flex-container .row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-container .row .col-sm-6,
.flex-container .row .col-md-3 {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex-container .row .col-sm-6 .text-center,
.flex-container .row .col-md-3 .text-center {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="container flex-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/500x500" alt="" class="responsive"></div>
      <div class="text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti doloribus eius beatae nihil, reiciendis ex placeat facere dolores, commodi eveniet tempore ratione, et, ducimus error cum. Architecto et, facilis assumenda.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/500x300" alt="" class="responsive"></div>
      <div class="text-center">Aliquam rem culpa, facere labore dolore autem pariatur quos, animi voluptatibus aut voluptas itaque obcaecati voluptatum quod eveniet consectetur libero adipisci laudantium consequuntur, delectus corporis! Tempora dignissimos eligendi, excepturi non.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/500x500" alt="" class="responsive"></div>
      <div class="text-center">Et eum, aliquid aliquam molestiae ducimus ipsa nam minus similique magni, ullam est, reprehenderit sunt impedit error distinctio minima nulla quod consequuntur. Earum beatae sunt cumque, doloribus quasi numquam quos!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/500x500" alt="" class="responsive"></div>
      <div class="text-center">Quae commodi asperiores perspiciatis, assumenda maxime necessitatibus qui. Incidunt, expedita voluptas nihil dolor ab nam, officia fugit quae voluptatum nulla sapiente alias asperiores atque voluptates consectetur cumque facilis minus beatae.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/500x500" alt="" class="responsive"></div>
      <div class="text-center">In atque ab odio est quia fugit quam blanditiis perspiciatis doloribus minus? Nulla expedita sequi quam vitae quaerat eveniet cum at, deserunt molestias explicabo. Cupiditate unde eligendi reprehenderit, accusamus numquam.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/500x500" alt="" class="responsive"></div>
      <div class="text-center">Veritatis quasi dolorem sunt itaque, sit officia blanditiis architecto possimus. Vitae repudiandae aperiam nostrum pariatur, odit eligendi, vero. Alias id adipisci culpa, vitae hic porro provident doloribus qui quisquam possimus.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/500x500" alt="" class="responsive"></div>
      <div class="text-center">Voluptate maxime quasi sequi nobis repudiandae optio nesciunt sapiente, ipsa eaque itaque numquam velit iusto atque, hic officiis id quidem minima consectetur illo repellat iure molestiae ipsam minus. Quae, ipsum!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
      <div class="thumbnail"><img src="https://placehold.it/500x500" alt="" class="responsive"></div>
      <div class="text-center">Impedit ipsa nemo libero in maiores, aperiam earum assumenda minus animi, ut necessitatibus, a ea. Illo et, dolorum velit repellat optio nam, iusto, ea nesciunt nostrum sunt ipsam odit nisi.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

For your PHP code I believe this should generate the same HTML as I am using

```
<div class="container flex-container">
    <div class="row">
        <?php
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) { ?>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src = "getimage2.php?id=
<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" alt = "
<?php echo ucfirst($row['jigsaw_title']); ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="caption text-center">
                <h3>
                    <?php echo ucfirst($row['jigsaw_title']); ?></h3>
                <p>
                    <?php echo $row['jigsaw_size_wmm']."mm x ".$row['jigsaw_size_hmm']."mm / ".mmToIn($row['jigsaw_size_wmm'])."in x ".mmToIn($row['jigsaw_size_hmm'])."in\n"; ?>    
                    <p>
                        <a href='#myModal1' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' id='custId' data-toggle='modal' data-id='".$row['id']."' ><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'>
                            </i></a>
                        <a href='#myModal2' class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' id='editrecord' data-toggle='modal' data-id='".$row['id']."'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'>
                            </i></a>
                        <a href='#myModal3' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' id='deleterecord' data-toggle='modal' data-id='".$row['id']."'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'>
                            </i></a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php   
                                        }
        ?>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if you have any questions or if this doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Its working better but how would I get the text contents to align to the bottom of the col-sm div so that all the jigsaw info is all the in the bottom of the div?

Comment: @ZJGreen just updated the question, let me know if that's what you mean.

Comment: That's working great now, thanks for your assistance, now all I have to do is add my pagination, but I think I have the sorted, Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are displaying only four images per row, try below code:

```
<?php $cnt = 0; ?>
<div class="row"><?php
    while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {?>
        <?php $cnt += 1; ?>
        <div class = "col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class = "thumbnail">
                <img src = "getimage2.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" alt = "<?php echo ucfirst($row['jigsaw_title']); ?>">
            </div>
            <div class = "caption text-center">
                <h3><?php echo ucfirst($row['jigsaw_title']); ?></h3>
                <p>
                    <?php echo $row['jigsaw_size_wmm']."mm x ".$row['jigsaw_size_hmm']."mm / ".mmToIn($row['jigsaw_size_wmm'])."in x ".mmToIn($row['jigsaw_size_hmm'])."in\n"; ?> 
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a href='#myModal1' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' id='custId' data-toggle='modal' data-id='".$row['id']."' ><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></i></a>
                    <a href='#myModal2' class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' id='editrecord' data-toggle='modal' data-id='".$row['id']."'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></i></a>
                    <a href='#myModal3' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' id='deleterecord' data-toggle='modal' data-id='".$row['id']."'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i></a>
                </p>
             </div>
       </div>
       <?php
            if($cnt == 4){
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<div class = 'row'>";
                $cnt = 0;
            }
       ?>
    <?php } ?>  
</div>
```

The solution is if you already displayed four images, create another **`row`** for the next images.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, and did not work for me, Thanks anyway, @Jhecht's solution worked for me.

Comment: Ok, nice to hear that your question is answered. Anyway this solution works on me.